# How to Unit Test in F# using dictionary

Tags: unit-testing, f#, functional-programming

having problems unable to figure out why I can execute this code in f# unit testing

```
// testing the dictionary method 
   let callStatus = dict[
        "busy", "Monday";
        "quite", "Tuesday";
        "okay", "Friday";
        "ok", "Wednesday";
   ]

   Assert.AreEqual(("Wednesday",callStatus.['ok']))
```

the Error I am getting is Unmatched '[' which does not make sense as the same code in Console application works fine.

any support would be appreciated.

Comment: the `'ok'` looks off - shouldn't it be `"ok"`?

Comment: Correct it should be , that appears to have fix the problem

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how but it appears by replacing the '' single quote marks with "" the error disappears

```
// testing the dictionary method 
let `` testing diction  `` () = 

    let callStatus = dict[
        "busy", "Monday";
        "quite", "Tuesday";
        "okay", "Friday";
        "ok", "Wednesday";
        ]

    Assert.AreEqual("Wednesday",callStatus.["ok"])
```

if someone can double check that I am correct, I would really appreciate this as I am a newbie.

Comment: Single quotes are for char literals, double are for strings.

Answer (score 1):

Is this line correct:

```
Assert.AreEqual(("Wednesday",callStatus.['ok']))
```

Shouldn't it be

```
Assert.AreEqual("Wednesday",callStatus.["ok"])
```

**UPDATE:**

Added double quotes as well.